# Can I upgrade my MacBook Pro using "generic" RAM?

Tags: macbook-pro, memory

Has anyone tried just buying generic RAM (which is 1/2 the price) such as the Kingston or Corsair brands? I figure if it works just as well as the $200 pairs, why not! I am open to other suggestions as well.

Comment: Yes.  I am running 16GB of RAM in my 2011 MBP.  Apple actually has documentation on how to do this.  Just use RAM with the right specs and you should be fine.

Comment: @jason Thanks! Could you point me to where you bought it from or the documentation even...

Comment: You won't even void your warranty by upgrading your RAM.

Comment: what do you think of the one listed here?http://www.macmemory.com/macbook.asp#BlackBezel

Comment: Other World Computing (their URL is MacSales.com) is a good place to look. http://goo.gl/ZMHrx

Comment: I bought mine from Fry's - it was either Kingston or Crucial.  Any notebook RAM from a decent manufacturer that meets the specs should be fine.

Comment: Apple docs - http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1270?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Comment: iFixIt has wonderful visual guides for upgrading RAM and HDD in MBP - http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Installing-MacBook-Pro-15-Inch-Unibody-Early-2011-RAM/5905/1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can buy third party RAM.  I usually buy [Crucial](http://www.crucial.com) RAM.  As long as it is made to be compatible with your machine (Same Bus Speed and such).  Usually, you can search these companies sites for RAM for your specific make and model MBP and they will have suggestions for it.

You can sometimes even put in more RAM than Apple says it can.  The companies test newer machines to see how much RAM they can handle.  For instance, the new current gen MBP only supports 8GB according to Apple, but 16GB of RAM will still work and won't cause any problems. It will work perfectly.

I am running 8GB of RAM in my machine, it cost me 46 dollars with shipping over 200 dollars from Apple.

Just be sure to keep you old RAM just in case your new RAM goes bad, which it most likely won't, but that way you have back up RAM to use in just such an occasion.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a ton guys!!! Now I just have too many choices! lol!